# Find a subset of an array satisfying some condition

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Suppose that an array of N numbers is given.

How to find a subset that its sum is multiple of N?

I want to know the best approach.

The recursive function would be the right choice, but stack overflow for large number N isn't allowed.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```js
const arr = [];
const TOTAL_NUM = 5;
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUM; i++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(Math.random() * TOTAL_NUM) + 1);
    sum += arr[i];
}

const mod = sum % TOTAL_NUM;
for (let i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUM; i++) {
    let sum = arr[i]
    let found = false;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < TOTAL_NUM; j++) {
        sum += arr[j];
        if (sum % TOTAL_NUM === 0 || (sum - mod) % TOTAL_NUM === 0) {
            found = true;
            console.log('Sum = %d', sum);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) break;
}
```

Comment: Any subset or the smallest subset, or the smallest multiple?

Comment: any subset would be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my question and to be evaluated by audiences.
This is my current code. I'll explain.

Assume we have an array of N numbers.

In loop for variable i = 0, we get N subsets and its inner sums. If there is at least one subset that its sum is multiple of N, it will be a solution. If not,  the value of (sum % N) would take one value between 1 and (N-1). There exist N sums and (N-1) possible remainders. Therefore, there exist at least one pair (n, m) that n-th sum and m-th sum would have the same remainder, where 0 < n < m < N. 
In this case, the sum of a subset [arr[n+1], arr[n+2], ... arr[m]] would be the multiple of N. So we can find n and m to solve this problem.

Below is the code to find n and m.

```js
const arr = [];
const TOTAL_NUM = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUM; i++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(Math.random() * TOTAL_NUM * 10) + 1);
}
console.log(arr.join(', '));

// find n and m
for (let i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUM; i++) {
    let sum = 0;
    found = false;
    for (let j = i; j < TOTAL_NUM; j++) {
        sum += arr[j];
        if (sum % TOTAL_NUM === 0) {
            found = true;

            // output result
            console.log('Sum = %d, n = %d, m = %d', sum, i, j);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) break;
}
```

As you can see, this code requires N * (N-1) / 2 loop, and no memory. Even for very large N, it would take a few milliseconds to find n and m. 
It took about 20~80ms to find a solution for N = 10000000 on my computer(Core i5 4460 @ 2.90GHz).

Comment: This, `[arr[n+1], arr[n+2], ... arr[m]]`, would be considered a "subarray," which is a subset of contiguous elements from the list. Your question description should be clarified if you are looking for a subarray rather than a subset, which could be any combination of elements from the list.

Comment: You might want to add a small, non-trivial example here and in the question description of input and expected output and an explanation why that is the output.

Comment: I wrote that I want to find a subset. If I can find such a subarray, can't it be a solution? What I wanted to say is that it is more easy and fast to find a subarray and that such a subarray exists for sure.

Comment: How can it exist for sure if we do not know in advance what the input is?

Comment: Please carefully my explanation. I didn't make any assumptions on input.

Answer (score 0):

We don't necessarily need to recurse. We can iterate on the known remainders so far.

JavaScript code below (this is exhaustive; we could have a more space efficient version to return just one subset by adjusting what we store):

```js
// 'rem' stands for "remainder"
function f(A){
  let N = A.length
  let rems = {0: [[]]}
  
  for (let a of A){
    let newRems = {}
    for (let rem in rems){
      let newRem = (a + Number(rem)) % N
      newRems[newRem] = (rems[newRem] || []).concat(
        rems[rem].map(x => x.concat(a)))
    }
    
    newRems[a % N] = (rems[a % N] || []).concat([[a]])
    rems = Object.assign(rems, newRems)
  }

  return rems[0].slice(1)
}

var A = [1, 6, 2, 3, 4]

console.log(JSON.stringify(A))
console.log(`N: ${A.length}`)
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A)))
```